# Функция strcasechr: как она работает?

Tags: c, функции

Аналогично `strcasestr` только без учета регистра?

Comment: Нет ли опечатки в вопросе? А вообще читайте мануалы - это полезно 8-)
например, http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=strcasestr&category=3&russian=0

Comment: Что-то ни гугл, ни `man` не находят ни `stscasechr`, ни `strcasechr`.

Comment: прошу прощения! опечатка, действительно. Функция strcasechr

Comment: @codergirl: так и `strcasechr` не гуглится.